Why would my fresh install boot into BusyBox? How to list packages that depend on BusyBox?
I just encountered something that I don't understand, and I'm afraid it could possibly be hack or malware related...  I put my computer into suspend mode and was unable to wake it, the screen powered back on but it remained black.  I did a hard power off by holding down the power button.  Upon powering up again, it booted into a BusyBox console.  I rebooted again, and it booted into Ubuntu as expected.  I very recently installed Ubuntu 24.10 and have not explicitly installed BusyBox.  I do not know how BusyBox has come to be installed.  So a few questions:

Does BusyBox come installed by default on Ubuntu 24.10, or does it come with any major packages?  The only possibility is possibly Steam.
How can I find out when and why BusyBox was installed?
Is it possible that BusyBox could be a remote environment for a 3rd party to backdoor into?  It bothers me that it made its way onto my system, and furthermore why would it randomly boot into a BusyBox environment?


You mention a release, but don't provide any clues as to what Ubuntu 24.10 product you installed; but yes busybox is a default package which can appear when there are problems with your boot; eg. https://releases.ubuntu.com/24.10/ubuntu-24.10-live-server-amd64.manifest shows what is found on a Ubuntu 24.10 Server image (amd64), but install options will dictate what was actually installed on your unstated 24.10 system

@guiverc It's standard Ubuntu Desktop 24.10 with the 'additional tools and drivers' that requires an internet connection during install.  This uses the GNOME desktop environment if I'm not mistaken.

Busybox is part of the normal install of Ubuntu. It is a useful toolkit for diagnosing and recovering from several types of boot failures.
You were not hacked. You merely happened to encounter one of those boot failures.

Ok, interesting...  I have used many Ubuntu and Linux releases with a variety of desktop environments over the years and I have never encountered BusyBox without me explicitly installing and configuring the environment to be used.  Mint, Cinnamon, standard ('vanilla' to keep up with the flavoring trope :P) have all been installed on the same laptop and I have encountered random boot failures that caused it to boot into a terminal console.  But it's never been BusyBox...  Do you know if this is new in version 24.xx?

After digging I now know that BusyBox has been a part of Ubuntu for quite some time.  But now I'm wondering why I've never seen it until now.
